# Accept mobile but not fixed-line numbers using Google's libphonenumber library

Tags: c#, libphonenumber

I'm using Google's libphonenumber library in order to validate mobile numbers, but I want to just accept mobile numbers and refuse fixed-line numbers.

Is this possible?

Here is my phone number validation code:

```
    public bool MobileNumberContentValidator(string mobileNumber, string region)
    {
        var phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
        var phone = phoneUtil.Parse(mobileNumber, region.ToUpper());

        if (phoneUtil.IsValidNumber(phone))//its validate all kind of phone numbers
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

This method validates both fixed-line and mobile numbers. I want to reject fixed-line numbers and accept mobile numbers.

Comment: To be honest: your question is not clear enough. Refuse phone numbers? What does that even mean? And if you ask "is this possible?", it will result in a yes/no answer.

Comment: You want to validate if a number is mobile phone number? It really depends on your country, state, provider combination, whether you want country codes, etc. So please add samples of all types of inputs, the ones to be rejected and ones to be accepted.

Comment: Also Please post code minimum code that is required, I don't think the try catch block is anything related to the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found this in order to accept just mobile numbers:

```
if (phoneUtil.GetNumberType(mobile) == PhoneNumberType.MOBILE) return true
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it would be better to use the 'PhoneNumberType' enum:  
_PhoneNumberUtil.GetNumberType(_Number) == PhoneNumberType.MOBILE